# How to prevent VSCode from converting tabs to spaces when you save a C file?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with Visual Studio Code. Every time I save a C file VS Code automatically converts the indentation from tabs to double spaces. Is there a possible way to prevent it from converting to spaces, and if possible, is it possible to make tabs the default type of indentation?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a possible way to prevent it from converting to spaces?

Yes. Change the tab-size with your desired size:

[image: Tab Size Setting in VS Code]

> Is it possible to make tabs the default type of indentation?

Yes. Uncheck this option:

[image: Insert Spaces Setting in VS Code]

Now, when you save the file, you'll see your expected results. But, note that keeping the spaces instead of tabs makes the code look better.